# QGIS: Creating regular equidistant points whith distance in meters

Tags: distance, raster, points, qgis, meter

I need a set of equidistant points (like a raster) each in a 1km distance to the next over a certain area, in my case Germany. I know the feature "regular points" in QGis where I can do just that but the distance you can enter there is not in meters but in coordinates or something. I tried it in WGS 84 as well as in EPSG:31467 (Gauss-Kruger, common in Germany) which is supposed to be in meters but the results seem to be the same..
I just can't find a way to set a certain distance in meters.

Please help :) Thanks!

Comment: You would probably get more attention to this question on http://gis.stackexchange.com/